# How to create objects on tradingview chart in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tradingview-api

I need to put my own objects on Tradingview chart in my WebApp, for example different lines or boxes.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lonJ6.png)

How can I implements this using `vue.js`. I found this libs: [[1]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-trading-view), [[2]](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts), but there are now information about this.

Now i only added single chart on the page

```
<template>
  <div>
    <VueTradingView :options="{
      locale: 'ru',
    }"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import VueTradingView from 'vue-trading-view';
  export default {
    name: 'Home',
    data: () => ({
    }),

    components: {
      VueTradingView,
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please show the code you've tried, and state specifically what you expect to happen, and specifically what is going wrong that isn't meeting your expectations. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) section.

Comment: @AndyRay my question exactly about code, i did not find information how to implement this. I only find how to put the chart on the page, but nothing about how to add objects

Comment: It doesn't look like the vue component supports custom data sets, it just passes props straight through to the TradingView widget, which isn't very customizable. https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts#es6-via-npm has an example of adding custom data sets, but it looks like you'd have to do custom work to also get real stock data into this core chart library.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/ehsan-shv/vue-tradingviewWidgets